# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myapp.SearchFlight$OnwardDatePickerFragment

Tags: android, android-datepicker

Why am I getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, the damn class is right there.

**code**

```
public class SearchFlight extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnItemClickListener, IOnRequestCompleted, OnDateChangedListener {

    private static OnwardDatePickerFragment date_picker_fragment_onward;
    private static ReturnDatePickerFragment date_picker_fragment_return;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.flights_tab);

        --line number 100 --> date_picker_fragment_onward = new OnwardDatePickerFragment();
        date_picker_fragment_return = new ReturnDatePickerFragment();

        ... lot other code...
    }
    public class OnwardDatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            date_picker_return.init(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay,
                    null);
            calendar.set(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay);
            toDay.setText(Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
            toMonthDay.setText(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
            returnDate = calendar.getTime();

        }
    }
    .. lot other code ..
}
```

**exception**

```
12-19 10:38:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(6529): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.icango.SearchFlight$OnwardDatePickerFragment
12-19 10:38:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(6529):     at com.icango.SearchFlight.onCreate(SearchFlight.java:100)
12-19 10:38:19.034: E/AndroidRuntime(6529):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing static initialization of `OnwardDatePickerFragment` class.
don't make it like this.

Do like this:

```
 private  OnwardDatePickerFragment date_picker_fragment_onward;
```

Instead of it:

```
 private static OnwardDatePickerFragment date_picker_fragment_onward;
```

Comment: then make your subclass static @Siddharth

Comment: you are getting this error because..compiler time it is getting the class `OnwardDatePickerFragment` but not runtime. its not getting the classpath of your class

Comment: try to clean your project and check the dependency you added and rebuild

Comment: i tried your way and it is working fine with me. so i am not getting the actual reason of this error...